# Firebase Functions and GDPR

Tags: google-cloud-functions, privacy

I'm considering crating a simple API to serve my app. Basically it would be a very simple monitoring system (sending a true/false value) and uploading it to database or BigQuery. According to the Firebase documentation, the Functions service stores the IP address temporarily (which is considered personal data) - https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/.

Does it mean that I would need to ask the users for the consent to use this API to comply with GDPR?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal issue and they are specifically off topic here